# Assignments graded and returned in Classroom can show the state as TURNED_IN or CREATED instead of RETURNED with Google Classroom API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-classroom

So i Have a Google Sheet that pulls the grades from my Google Classroom. For some reason one of the assignments has not been pulling the correct information. Instead of getting a state of RETURNED I get either TURNED_IN or CREATED. The assigments were graded and returned through Google Classroom. So far I have only noticed this problem with only one assignment.

To pull the grades I use the Google Classroom API
`Classroom .Courses .CourseWork .StudentSubmissions .list(dSCourseId, '-',{userId : id.toString()}) .studentSubmissions`
I do this for each student enrolled in the Google Classroom, and it works fine for all but one assignment.

Comment: About `I do this for each student enrolled in the Google Classroom, and it works fine for all but one assignment.`, when you confirm the value of `submissionHistory` of the user `but one assignment`, what result did you obtain? Was your expected result included in the value? I would like to think of the reason for your current issue by correctly replicating your current situation.

Comment: No, I am not getting the expected results from submissionHistory for the one assignment. It does not have a record of the assignment being graded and returned, it only shows it being created and, for some, being turned in. The other assignments that work properly show the entire history correctly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `No, I am not getting the expected results from submissionHistory for the one assignment. It does not have a record of the assignment being graded and returned, it only shows it being created and, for some, being turned in. The other assignments that work properly show the entire history correctly.`, in this case, I'm worried that the current value of `Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.list` might be the correct value. So, how about checking the situations of each assignment, again?

Comment: Thank you for your help. It looks like it was a Google glitch as the issue has resolved itself without any intervention on my part.